# php file, calling function to set value

Tags: php, sql, function

I have a site page (index.php) that is currently using a function from a class file to determine whether or not to show/hide 2 links on the page. This works properly, however, we now have a new class file using a different database that we want to use to do the same thing.

In my function below (OrderFormLinks.php) it's calling on a mysql table and I'm mainly concerned with the `$this->min_order = $row['order'];` line. If the 'order' row has a 0 it should hide the links, and a 1 should show the links. More specifically, in my index.php file, I want the 0 in the database to set those session values to 1. The section that's commented out is the other method that currently works.

The page loads and everything works fine, but as I have it now it hides the links regardless of the database value, and if I set it to '1' in my if statement it shows the links.

Does it look like I"m declaring/calling correctly?

Here is the function from my OrderFormLinks.php file containing the class OrderFormLinks:

```
function setCustdataObj(CustomerDataNew &$custdata)
{
    $this->custdata = $custdata;
}

function min_message($cust = null)
{

    if ($cust == null) {
        $d = $this->custdata->getCustNum();
    } else {
        $d = $cust->getCustNum();
    }
    $this->connectDB_mysql();
    $co_num = $this->of->co_nn + 0;


    $sql = "select * from min_dealer where dealer = '{$d}'";
    $result = $this->mysqli_new->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        //throw new Exception("Error: {$this->mysqli->error}");
    }

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $this->min_show_message = $row['message'];
        $this->min_order = $row['order'];
    }
}
```

And here is my declaration and if statement in my index.php file:

```
    $oflinks = new OrderFormLinks();
    $oflinks->setCustdataObj($custData);
    $oflinks->min_message();

    if ($oflinks->min_order == 0) {
        $_SESSION['ops1'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['ops2'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['ops3']   = 1;
        $_SESSION['ops4'] = 1;
    }

    // if (!$custdata->isDealerOeAllowed()) {
    //     $_SESSION['ops1'] = 1;
    //     $_SESSION['ops2'] = 1;
    //     $_SESSION['ops3'] = 1;
    //     $_SESSION['ops4'] = 1;
    // }
```

Comment: Everything looks fine here... Though I don't understand why you are using a while loop when retrieving data from database?? Are you receiving more than one line? If so, only the last will impact as you re set the value on every row. Could actually be the problem.

Comment: Also looking more closely at your code, it seems you have created an anti patern... You can set this->cust but you can also pass customer to the function... In any circumstance, this->min_order is impacted. This is weird! Also, think of maybe using get_min_order() instead of having to make 3 different setup calls.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.I agree there is some weirdness here, it's inherited legacy code that needs to be changed/updated, however, my task at the moment was just fix it so that the min_order from the database being 0 would set the session variables to 1. I was just confused on the best way to do that here

Comment: Then, I'd focus on my first comment...

Comment: Ok, I do believe the while loop is fetching multiple lines because it could affect different users logging in and would need the value specifically for that user. This function is working on another page as well

Comment: place a echo inside the while and see... Best way to figure out where it's coming from...